# How to write the test case for Controller?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I am new to unit test.

Please help me to write test case code for following code:

```
 $scope.convertToInt = function (str) {
                if (!isNumberEmpty(str) && !isNaN(str)) {
                    return parseInt(str, 10);
                }
                return "";
            }
```

I have tried like this, but not able to do.

```
describe('ConfigurationTestController', function() {

  beforeEach(module('usp.configuration')); 

  describe('ConfigurationController', function () {
        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller('ConfigurationController', {
                '$scope': scope
            });
        }));
    });
});
```

Please tell me how can I write.......

Comment: I tried to search on Google, but I am not getting how to pass the str through test case, after that only I have posted.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to modify your code a bit. you don't need to use `describe` twice in your test case.

```
(function() {

    "use strict";

    describe("test suite for Configuration test controller", function() {

        var scope = null;
        beforeEach(module("usp.configuration"));
        beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $controller("ConfigurationController", {
                $scope: scope
            });
        }));

        it("should convert to int", function() {
            expect(scope.convertToInt("2")).to.equal(2);
        });

        it("should return empty string", function() {
            expect(scope.convertToInt("asd")).to.equal("");
        });
    });

}());
```

Comment: I tried the same way also, but before and now also I am getting same error:  Error: [$injector:unpr]

Comment: can you provide the stack trace of you error in the question? Also if you click on the error from browser console it will take you to the angular website where you can see more details. Most probably you are missing some dependency

Comment: angular.module('usp.configuration').controller('ConfigurationController', ConfigurationController);
  
    ConfigurationController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', 'configurationService', 'productService', 'notification', 'sitemapService', 'DYNAMIC_NOTIFICATION_API_HOSTNAME', 'fogsettingsService', 'signalrService', 'policyService'];           I have all these dependencies, so I have to inject all these in Test Case....

Comment: Yes it is working but after excluding all service dependencies. Now I am trying with injecting the service dependencies.

Comment: I edited your code and trying to add dependencies. Is this correct way to add? But I am getting error...